# Complicated Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to formulas and conditional formatting.

I have a spreadsheet where employees submit requests for adjustments to their time worked. Column  B is the date of the request, Column C is their username, and Column H is the reason. I want to create a conditional formatting formula to check if the there are any duplicates, so essentially,

Highlight row 2 if: value in B2 exists anywhere else in column B, AND value in C2 exists anywhere else in column C, AND value in H2 exists anywhere else in column H).

And I need this to work for every row.

Comment: Here is an example of the sheet (false names and details)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw8hvFzQ1Ix4Y2g0d3RsdWNFVEk

I would want the second and third rows, and the last two rows to highlight because on the same date, the same name had the same reason.

Comment: @pnuts It's how I understand the question. Highlight the rows with duplicates. What makes you think it's not what he wants?

Comment: @teylyn when I used your formula it highlighted Jack on Row one, even though Jack doesn't have 2 entries for the same date. Also, It only applied the formatting to the date box. Any suggestions?

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't working, because those values do exist in the column. It's not qualifying them by rows, if that makes any sense.

So in my actual sheet with over 300 rows, it sees that Dave exists multiple times, and 5/8/17 exists multiple times, and Other exists multiple times, so it applies the formatting. But I need it to see if 5/8/17, Dave, Other exist in the same row multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a helper column for that. Use a formula like this to concatenate the values of Date, Name, Reason and Notes, for example in cell L2 and copied down.

```
=A2&B2&G2&H2
```

Now you can apply conditional formatting to the range A2 to H2 using the custom formula

```
=countif($L:$L,$L2)>1
```

You can hide the helper column if it upsets your spreadsheet design.

[image]

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!